# Vertex AI Online Text Prediction Request

Tags: prediction, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am using multiple models deployed on vertex AI for making predictions on text data.
I saw pricing [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/pricing#:%7E:text=0.05%20per%20hour-,Prediction,the%20second%20request%20(1%2C500)%2C%20and%20one%20for%20the%20third%20request%20(600).,-Prediction%20charges%20for) . So my question is about prediction format. How many texts can I send in a single request and how these are counted. For example the request:

```
    {
    "instances":[
        {
            "text":"DoiT is a great company."

        },
        {
            "text":"The beach was nice but overall the hotel was very bad."
        },
        {
            "text": "I feel sad about it."
        }
 ]
}
```

Does the length of **instances** array is counted as number of record? Also, how many text I can send per instance for making prediction request?